# why $BASH_SUBSHELL doesn't increase in pipe

Tags: bash, pipe, subshell

I know  pipe will create subshell.

I test `$BASH_SUBSHELL` and `$BASHPID` , and find `$BASH_SUBSHELL` doesn't increase in pipe

```
echo $BASH_SUBSHELL         # 0
echo $BASHPID               # 8347

echo $BASH_SUBSHELL | cat   # 0
echo $BASHPID | cat         # 9727

(echo $BASH_SUBSHELL)       # 1
(echo $BASHPID)             # 9778
```

Comment: What about `eval 'echo $BASH_SUBSHELL' | cat` or `{ echo $BASH_SUBSHELL } | cat`?

Comment: @choroba it works, but why $BASH_SUBSHELL  not increase in my example

Comment: I am not sure. The variable is probably expanded by the parent shell before running the subshell, but I cannot find the exact documentation and I am not going to search the source :-)

Comment: Even a command group `{ echo $BASH_SUBSHELL; } | cat` is enough to increment the value, so it looks like the `bash` parser needs some explicit clue in the command itself that a subshell will be spawned.

Answer (score 2):

When bash merely forks, sets up a command and execves it, it doesn't count it as a subshell.

For any kind of control structure, like command groups, if statements and while loops, where the shell actually has to be involved beyond setup, it does.

This is apparent from the bash source, `execute_command_internal` in `execute_cmd.c`.